# ERROR TransportClientFactory: Exception while bootstrapping client

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark job which works successfully with a small cluster, but starts to get a lot of the following errors in the first few minutes when it starts up. Any idea on how I can solve it? This is with PySpark 2.2.0 and mesos.

```
17/09/29 18:54:26 INFO Executor: Running task 5717.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5717)
17/09/29 18:54:26 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 5813
17/09/29 18:54:26 INFO Executor: Running task 5813.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5813)
17/09/29 18:54:26 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 5909
17/09/29 18:54:26 INFO Executor: Running task 5909.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5909)
17/09/29 18:54:56 ERROR TransportClientFactory: Exception while bootstrapping client after 30001 ms
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.
        at org.spark_project.guava.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient.sendRpcSync(TransportClient.java:275)
        at org.apache.spark.network.sasl.SaslClientBootstrap.doBootstrap(SaslClientBootstrap.java:70)
        at org.apache.spark.network.crypto.AuthClientBootstrap.doSaslAuth(AuthClientBootstrap.java:117)
        at org.apache.spark.network.crypto.AuthClientBootstrap.doBootstrap(AuthClientBootstrap.java:76)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:244)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.downloadClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:332)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:467)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$3.apply(Executor.scala:684)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$3.apply(Executor.scala:681)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:681)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.
        at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:276)
        at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:96)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient.sendRpcSync(TransportClient.java:271)
        ... 23 more
17/09/29 18:54:56 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from /10.0.1.25:37314 is closed
17/09/29 18:54:56 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://10.0.1.25:37314/files/djinn.spark.zip with timestamp 1506711239350
```